# iOS 14 UIPickerView color of the selected row

Tags: ios, uipickerview

[image]

in iOS 14 the UIPickerView has default a grey background on the selected Row,

I can't find a way to change it

Comment: you can do something like `datepicker.subviews[0].backgroundColor = .red`, applying white color and clear color won't work, plus this is not valid solution

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, the code:

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) { pickerView.subviews[1].backgroundColor = .clear }
```

needs to go in the following protocol method:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image] I solved my problem like this

`if #available(iOS 14.0, *) { pickerView.subviews[1].backgroundColor = .clear }`